# Quando utilizar a tag <figure>

Tags: html

Sei apenas que ela serve pra dar mais semântica para elementos visuais. Minhas dúvidas são:

- Quando devemos utilizar?
- Quais são as boas práticas?
- Existem alternativas a ela? Quando devo utilizá-las?

Comment: Você se refere a [tag <figure>](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/figure)?

Comment: @Randrade exatamente.

Comment: Particularmente porque tem o `<figcaption>` associado que permite dar uma legenda ao elemento

Comment: Então sempre que eu quiser ter uma legenda em uma img eu coloco um figure.